# Bounded variations on $U-\{0\}$ $\Longrightarrow$ bounded variations on $U$?

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Given $U\in\mathbb{R}$ a non-empty neighbourhood of $0$ and $f$ a function of bounded variations (BV) on $U-\{0\}$. Can I deduce that $f$ is BV on $U$?

Comment: What is your definition for a "function of bounded variation" on an arbitrary set $E$?  It is commonly defined on an interval $[a,b]$, but there are several definitions available if you want to define the concept on an arbitrary set of reals.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson It seems "function of BV" can be defined on a total ordered set, and if I'm correct, $[a,0)\cup (0,b]$ with $a<0<b$ is a total order set. And I know only one definition, which is that for any subdivision of the total ordered set, the sum of the norm of the images of two consecutive subdivisions boundaries should be finite.

Comment: So basically just an upper bound on $\sum |F(b_i)-F(a_i)|$ is all you want.  Well, wouldn't the addition of the point $0$ add at most two elements $|F(0)-F(a_i)|$ and $|F(b_i)-F(0)|$ to the sum? Your function is bounded on $U$ so you can still find an upper bound with a little work.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Well I agree if $f$ is bounded on $U$ but how do you know that? Couldn't $f$ be BV on $U-\{0\}$ and diverged in $0$?

Comment: "Bounded variation" implies "bounded."  If $M$ is an upper bound for all those sums then you can pick a point $a$ and, using any point $x$,   claim that $|F(x)-F(a)|\leq M$ and hence that $|F(x)|\leq M + $|F(a)|$.  Maybe not something you notice when your first learn the terminology but certainly something you will never forget after using it for a while.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson You helped me clarifying my ideas, thank you. My question is in fact more subtle than this. I was able to reformulate my problem, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494371/if-f-f-f-are-bounded-a-e-is-f-of-bounded-variation-everywhere.