# If $f,f',f''$ are bounded a.e., is $f'$ of bounded variation everywhere?

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, bounded-variation

Assume the function $f$ is such that everywhere except in $0$:

- $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$
- $f$ is twice differentiable everywhere except in $0$
- $f'$ and $f''$ are bounded everywhere except in $0$

**Question** I the derivative of $f$, in the weak sense, of bounded variation?

**What I think** $f'$ and $f''$ are not defined on $\mathbb{R}$ but by by extension, in the measure sense, $f'(t)=v(t)+\alpha H(t)$ where $v$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and $H$ is the Heaviside function. Similarly, $f''(t)=a(t)+\alpha\delta(t)$ where $a=v'$ and $\delta$ is the Dirac function.

$\alpha H$ is of bounded variation, $a$ is bounded on $\mathbb R$, so $v$ is Lipschitz hence of bounded variation, and so is their sum $f'$.

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think what "by by extension, in the measure sense" means, so I'm ignoring everything after that.

1. Since $f''$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)$, it follows that $f'$ is Lipschitz on  $(0,\infty)$. Hence, $f'$ has bounded variation on any interval of the form $(0,b]$.
2. Since $f''$ is bounded on $(-\infty,0)$, it follows that $f'$ is Lipschitz on  $(-\infty,0)$. Hence, $f'$ has bounded variation on any interval of the form $[a,0)$.
3. Regardless of the value at $0$ (as long as it's somehow defined), $f'$ is BV on $[a,b]$; this follows by considering any partition of $[a,b]$, inserting $0$ into the partition, and adding things up.

But check whether your definition of BV requires the function to be defined everywhere (since $f'(0)$ appears to be undefined).

Comment: What if $f$ is the Dirac distribution? You're not using the assumption "$f$ bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ which I think, should be added in 3 (so that "inserting 0 into the partition" does not make the variation infinite).

Comment: Dirac distribution is not a function. Also, if you are not completely satisfied by this answer, please don't mark it as accepted.